# Have I converted this php sample for Facebook authentication correctly into c#?

Tags: c#, php, facebook

I'm trying to write a c# version of some php sample code for Facebook authentication which I found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/ The php in the example is:

```
define('YOUR_APP_ID', 'your app id ');
define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', 'your app secret');

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret) {
  $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $app_secret) != $args['sig']) {
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}
```

And my C# version is:

```
private bool CheckFacebookAuthentication()
{
    var appSecret = "??????????";
    var appId = "?????";
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["fbs_" + appId];

    var payload = "";
    foreach (var key in cookie.Values.AllKeys.OrderBy(x => x))
    {
        if (key != "sig")
        {
            payload += key.Trim("\"".ToCharArray()) + "=" + cookie.Values[key].Trim("\"".ToCharArray());
        }
    }

    if (cookie.Values["sig"] == FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(payload + appSecret, "md5"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I appreciate that my c# version is not doing quite the same thing as the php i.e. it is just checking that the signature is valid and returning a boolean indicating this; whereas the php is returning an array if it is valid.

But the issue I have is that my c# version is not validating cookies that I would expect to be valid.  My experience of php is limited, so I expect I have misinterpreted something from the php example when writing my c# version.

Is there anything obviously wrong with my c# interpretation of this php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct translation, but you could replace `"\"".ToCharArray()` with just `'\"'`

Also, there is a pretty good SDK written in C# for Facebook here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

That is if you want to look at some more example code.

I've worked a lot with Facebook's Graph APIs and C#, so if there is anything specific you need help with, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is not the corresponding translation. As far as I can see it boils down to this line:

```
parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
```

Here in PHP the cookie string is trimmed by removing any '\' or '"' character (check the php manual for trim(...)) and **then** parsed whereas in C# you are currently trimming each value and key individually, try removing this.